# Homestead.yaml *Shell provisioner `args` must be a string or an array

Tags: vagrant, yaml, homestead

I was editing my homestead.yaml file and I am certain the indentation is correct -- I however get this following error:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

shell provisioner:
* Shell provisioner `args` must be a string or array.
* Shell provisioner `args` must be a string or array.
* Shell provisioner `args` must be a string or array.
* Shell provisioner `args` must be a string or array.
```

My homestead.yaml file:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
     - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders: 
     - map: ~/Sites
       to: /home/vagrant/Sites

sites: 
     - map: scheduleify.dev
       to: /home/vagrant/Sites/scheduleify/public

     - map: phpmyadmin.dev
       to: /home/vagrant/Sites/phpmyadmin

     - map: articles.dev
       to: /home/vagrant/Sites/learning-laravel5    

databases:
     - scheduleify

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
  - value: local
```

Any ideas on what is wrong with the file?

Comment: Any feedback on assumption about wrong indentation of the last line?

Comment: Thanks for the answer; that was it! Could have sworn I replied -- got swamped with work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Last line isn't indented correctly. Make sure it looks like

```
variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```

Also check that all paths on host machine exist.

Comment: Yep that did it! Indentation is such a pain.

Comment: Problem for me was that I had the "-" on the value part of my site setup. But, same principle. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, this solution helped fix my problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue but slightly different reason:

```
variables:
    - key: ON_HOMESTEAD
      value: true  # Error
```

The value `true` is invalid and should be `1`.

```
variables:
    - key: ON_HOMESTEAD
      value: 1
```